# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _contexts_AuthContext__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.useAuth) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-context

I'm trying to call the useAuth() function from AuthContext.tsx in my Navigation.tsx but I get an error saying my useAuth is not a function. Here are the steps I have taken to debug:

- Wrapping/Scope: AuthProvider is put where Navigation will be placed within (layout.tsx)
- Import/Export: `useAuth` is imported using curly brackets and is exported as a function.

I'm not sure where this issue is coming from.

```
// AuthContext.tsx
"use client"
import { createContext, useContext, useState, ReactNode } from "react";

interface AuthProviderProps {
    children: ReactNode;
}

interface AuthContextType {
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    login: () => void;
    logout: () => void;
}

// Create context
const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType | undefined>(undefined)

export const useAuth = () => {
    const context = useContext(AuthContext)
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error('useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider');
    }
    return context;
}

export const AuthProvider: React.FC<AuthProviderProps> = ({ children }: AuthProviderProps) => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false)

    const login = () => {
        setIsAuthenticated(true)
    }

    const logout = () => {
        setIsAuthenticated(false)
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, login, logout }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

```
// Navigation.tsx
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { navCategories } from '../config/navData';
import { useAuth } from '@/contexts/AuthContext';

export default function Navigation() {
    console.log(useAuth)
    const {isAuthenticated, login, logout} = useAuth();

    return (
        <nav className='bg-white border-b border-gray-200 py-4 shadow-sm'>
            <ul className='flex justify-center space-x-10'>
                {navCategories.map((category) => (
                    <li key={category.label} className='text-gray-600 hover:text-blue-600'>
                        <Link href={category.href}>
                            <span className='text-md font-semibold tracking-wide transition-colors duration-300'>
                                {category.label}
                            </span>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

```
// layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Navigation from "../components/Navigation"
import { AuthProvider } from "@/contexts/AuthContext";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: "Create Next App",
    description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
    children,
}: Readonly<{
    children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <html lang="en">
                <body className={inter.className}>
                    <Navigation />
                    {children}
                </body>
            </html>
        </AuthProvider>
    );
}
```

Comment: Looks like the sort of error you get in a production build. Have you tried rebuilding, making sure all changes are saved

Comment: Hmm code looks fine, it's not something to do with the "use client"? Maybe try putting that at the top of some other files too?
https://react.dev/reference/react/use-client

Comment: @LindenWells Adding `'use client'` at the top of AuthContext.tsx solved this issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Han your question already shows `'use client'` at the top of `AuthContext.tsx` 

Comment: @Phil I'm sorry, it's adding `'use client'` at the top of `Navigation.tsx`, not `AuthContext.tsx`